Environment Path Variables are deleting while updating python path using batch (.bat) File
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: Variables
SET DOWNLOAD_URL=https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.0/python-3.12.0-amd64.exe
SET PYTHON_INSTALLER=python-3.12.0-amd64.exe
SET PYTHON_PATH=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python312
SET SCRIPTS_PATH=%PYTHON_PATH%\Scripts

:: Step 1: Download Python installer if it doesn't exist
IF EXIST "%~dp0%PYTHON_INSTALLER%" (
    echo Python installer already exists.
) ELSE (
    echo Downloading Python installer from %DOWNLOAD_URL%...
    powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri '%DOWNLOAD_URL%' -OutFile '%~dp0%PYTHON_INSTALLER%'"
    IF NOT EXIST "%~dp0%PYTHON_INSTALLER%" (
        echo Failed to download the Python installer.
        pause
        exit /b 1
    )
)

:: Step 2: Install Python silently
echo Installing Python...
"%~dp0%PYTHON_INSTALLER%" /quiet InstallAllUsers=0 PrependPath=0 TargetDir=%PYTHON_PATH%

:: Step 3: Verify Python was installed successfully
IF NOT EXIST "%PYTHON_PATH%\python.exe" (
    echo Python installation failed.
    pause
    exit /b 1
)

:: Step 4: Get the current user PATH (before adding Python)
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims= " %%A IN ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment" /v Path 2^>nul') DO (
    IF "%%A"=="Path" SET OLD_PATH=%%B
)

:: Step 5: Set new paths (Python and Scripts) to the new path variable
SET NEW_PATH=!OLD_PATH!;%PYTHON_PATH%;%SCRIPTS_PATH%
echo NEW_PATH (before removing duplicates): !NEW_PATH!

:: Step 6: Remove duplicates (optional)
SET NEW_PATH=!NEW_PATH:"%PYTHON_PATH%"=!
SET NEW_PATH=!NEW_PATH:"%SCRIPTS_PATH%"=!

:: Log final NEW_PATH after removing duplicates
echo NEW_PATH (after removing duplicates): !NEW_PATH!

:: Step 7: Update the system PATH for the user
SETX PATH "!NEW_PATH!"

:: Step 8: Update the current CMD session PATH (immediate effect)
SET PATH=!NEW_PATH!

:: Step 9: Verify Python installation
echo Verifying Python installation...
python --version
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    echo Python not found in PATH. You may need to restart your system.
    pause
    exit /b 1
)

echo Python 3.12.0 installed successfully, added to user PATH.
pause
exit /b 0

Prepared Batch file and running the batch file to download , Install python 3.12.0 and add the Environment variables to the Path.
But it deleting all the existing other app paths from environment path variables.
Note : I need to download and install from batch file only (Not Powershell )

Regardless of your stated issue, and given that you are downloading using PowerShell, (in your shown code), already, please could you explain your Note, and also your inclusion of the [[tag:powershell]] tag.

For your issue, please open a Command Prompt window, type reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment" /v Path 2>nul, and press the [ENTER] key. Now type for /?, and press the [ENTER] key to learn about tokens, delimiters, and the variables assigned to each. In your current code, the variable %%A is being assigned to token 2, (delimited by spaces). So look at the output of the first command I told you to enter, and tell us the content of each second token. Are any of them the case sensitive string Path?

Please read: What is the best practice for adding a directory to the PATH environment variable on Windows? It is a very long answer explaining everything to know on updating persistent stored user or system environment variable PATH with a batch file. The batch file code with lots of comments (the REMmark lines) is complex but that is necessary to avoid a PATH corruption.

Your batch file does not work on path of batch file directory referenced with %~dp0 contains one or more !. I have seen in the past users who use directories with exclamation marks, most often because of having entered an account name with ! and therefore many directory paths like %USERPROFILE%\Downloads, %APPDATA%, %LOCALAPPDATA%, %TEMP% contain also an exclamation mark in expanded form. Do not enable delayed variable expansion already at top of your batch file. Enable it only where necessary. Your batch file should work also in: C:\Temp\  ;Development & Test 100% (!)

@Compo
Yes almost all of  them are case sensitive

BTW: Please open a command prompt window, run if /? and read the output usage help. You will not read anything about IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 or similar often seen conditions using the dynamic variable ERRORLEVEL with the syntax for referencing an environment variable. The reason is that the usage of %ERRORLEVEL% does often not work. The syntax to use is IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 which always works. See the chapter 4. Accessing the values of dynamic variables in Difference between Dynamic variables and Environment variables in CMD.

@satishVudata, you have replied to my comment, without having tried what it asked. I know that because your reply to it, is irrelevant. My best guess is that the content of the second token, i.e. %%A, will always be REG_EXPAND_SZ and therefore never Path! In that scenario what happens is that OLD_PATH is undefined, which subsequently resolves NEW_PATH to ;%PYTHON_PATH%;%SCRIPTS_PATH%, i.e. removes all existing content.

I should also mention that Step 6: is completely wrong too. The reason being that unless your 'python' and 'scripts' absolute paths contain unlikely poison characters, their inclusion within the expandable string  is not going to be doublequoted. That means it would be highly unexpected that the value string would contain either "%PYTHON_PATH%" or "%SCRIPTS_PATH%", and no duplicates would therefore be removed, leaving the value string for the NEW_PATH variable exactly as it was in Step 5:.

All of that would still be irrelevant if you, or some installer mechanism actually created the user Path variable value string properly in the first place, (which is a rarity). The values should show in the GUI as %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python312, and either %PYTHON_PATH%\Scripts, or %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts. The reason being that the values are supposed to be expandable strings, REG_EXPAND_SZ, (for variables to expand), not standard strings, REG_SZ. When you created your initial variables, they were wrongly expanded at SET to standard strings...

...that means that any correctly made expandable strings will never match with a standard string, unless another level of expansion is introduced to create a standard strings on both sides of a comparison. Essentially for a user account named satishVudata, the following are not a string match C:\Users\satishVudata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312 and %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python312.
